# nested asynchronous tasks (use CompletionStage in java)

Tags: java, concurrency

I use service (from library and i can't change it) that have 3 methods:

```
CompletionStage<AData> getAData(int id);
CompletionStage<BData> getBData(int id);
CompletionStage<Path> computePath(int id);
```

for my purpose i should get AData and BData, and then based on this values try compute some `Path`, and if i can't do it - use service call

so my code now look like:

```
 CompletionStage<Path> getPath(int id) {
      service.getAData(id).thenCombine(service.getBdata(id)), (a, b) -> 
         {
             Path result = computePathLocaly(a, b);
             return result != null ? 
                            result : 
                            service.computePath(id).toCompletableFuture().join();
         }
}
```

all work fine, but `toCompletableFuture().join()` looks awfully. 
wrap `result` to `CompletionStage` and return `CompletionStage<CompletionStage<Path>>` - even worse...

I'm belive that it's can be done more gracefully, but i can't realize how to... Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compose your `service.computePath(id)` call with the `computePathLocally` call

```
CompletionStage<Path> getPath(int id) {
      service.getAData(id).thenCombine(service.getBdata(id)), (a, b) -> 
             return computePathLocally(a, b);
         ).thenCompose((result) -> 
           return result != null ?
                     CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result) :
                     service.computePath(id);
         )
}
```

Comment: All so simple... Thanks!